# What cross browser css do I need to switch image/animated logo

Tags: css, image, svg, cross-browser

Basically I have an animated svg logo that works lovely in all browsers apart from Edge, so was wondering if there is a way to change it to a static svg when viewed on Edge or if anyone has an Edge fix for an animated svg?

Quite new to all of this and used a animated svg generator to produce the svg but am at a loss to know the best thing to fix this..?

```
<div class="logo">
<div class="custom">
<p>
<a href="/">
<img src="/img/ethos-tech-animated-logo.svg" alt="" class="l-black">
<img src="/img/ethos-tech-animated-logo-white.svg" alt="" class="l-white">
<img src="/img/ethos-tech-animated-logo.svg" alt="" class="l-color">
</a>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

It is the main logo and the current result can be found here: https://ethostec.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this could be done simply by using JS or PHP :

JS :

```
<script>
    if (/Edge/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        //It's Edge and you have to show the static logo
    }
</script>
```

PHP :

```
<?php
    if (preg_match('/Edge/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
        //It's Edge and you have to show the static logo
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for help, the most of it worked but i had to add an else to it to make it work the way i wanted it too.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    if (preg_match('/Edge/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
?>
    //Static version of logo
<?php
    }else{
?>
    //Animated version of logo
<?php                       
    }
?>
```